# Can i safely Disable Windows feature Hyper V on my Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-virtual-machine, haxm

I am using Azure VM with o/s Windows 10. I am using Visual Studio 2017 to develop xamarin cross platform app targeting all 3 , windows, android, ios.

When i try to run my android avd i get this warning:
[link](https://hemantmahajan08.files.wordpress.com/2018/12/nexus.png)

If i continue avd is loaded but no App is displayed.

Should i disable hyper V on the VM and install intel HAXM? Is it safe?
[link](https://hemantmahajan08.files.wordpress.com/2018/12/windows-features.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its your vm, you can do whatever you want. The only thing, you need D\E v3 series vms to run nested virtualization.

Comment: where would i find D/E v3 series option?

Comment: well, when you create the vm, or later just change the sku. on the portal, for example: https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/resize-virtual-machines/